# Selenium Python - finds head/title outside the frame after switching to frame

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to check that the right web page is opened by asserting that the `title` in the head equals `'Sales and Offering Space'`. 
This `head`/`title` is in an iframe element and not visible.

After I switch to the iframe, Selenium doesn't find the wanted `title` in the iframe (`'Sales and Offering Space'`). Instead, it finds the main page `title` outside the frame (`'E-banking'`) and my assertion fails.

I tried locating the right `title` by xpath (abs, rel, indexed) and by tag name, and all of them always found only the main title. 
Can someone help please?

After navigating to the tested page I have this code:

```
context.driver.switch_to_frame('bzeMainIframe')
title = WebDriverWait(context.driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'title')))
assert title.text == 'Sales and Offering Space', "Page title is '%s' instead of 'Sales and Offering Space'" % (context.driver.title)
```

Result:

> Assertion Failed: Page title is 'E-Banking' instead of 'Sales and
>   Offering Space'

In the next step I have a similar check with switching to iframe and checking the value of the element in the body, and this assertion is successful. So I think that the issue with above code might be related the the fact that the wanted element is in the head.

Application under test:

https://ebanking-demo-ch2.ubs.com/auth/login1
- click Login, then wait for a few seconds to be redirected, then click Offerings on the top menu.

The project uses Behave and there is a lot more code that I cannot copy here, but if needed I would push everything to github.

Comment: Not able to navigate to Offerings on the top menu though.

Comment: @cruisepandey , If the locale is set to German, on the Login page tap on "Sprache" and select "English". Then after login you'll see the "Offerings" tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `title` is hidden, then `title.text` will return you empty string. Also `context.driver.title` always returns title of main page. So

- `title.text == ""`,
- `context.driver.title == "E-Banking"`,
- `title.get_attribute('textContent') == "Sales and Offering Space"`

You can try to modify your code as below:

```
context.driver.switch_to_frame('bzeMainIframe')
title = WebDriverWait(context.driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'title')))
assert title.get_attribute('textContent') == 'Sales and Offering Space', "Page title is '%s' instead of 'Sales and Offering Space'" % (title.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, fixed! And I am getting the same (correct) result with either title.get_attribute('text') or title.get_attribute('textContent').

Comment: Yeap, there are some minor differences, but in this current case all such attributes(properties) as `text`, `textContent`, `innerHTML`, `innerText`, `outerText` will return the same output

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was having this exact problem, the title was hidden and I was getting NULL from `tool.find_element_by_xpath(".//title").text`  Then I find this, and everything works with `tool.find_element_by_xpath(".//title").get_attribute('textContent')`